# Android Bluetooth l2cap socket bind()

Tags: android, bluetooth, l2cap

Android version: 2.3.7

Kernel version: 2.6.35-14-CyanogenMod-Arco-Kalim arco@tuxbox #1

Mod version: CyanogenMod-7.1.0.1-click

The device has been fully rooted.

I have added piece of code in my project

which taken from Bluez Utils in hidd.c.

The code is the following:

```
if (bind(sk, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
    close(sk);
    return -1;
}
```

`bind()` keeps returning `-1`.

I added a line(`DisablePlugins = input`) to the bluetooth configuration in my Android device

`/system/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

The information I have is:
`sk:37`

`(struct sockaddr *) &addr=0x44597e90`

`sizeof(addr)=12`

`errno:13`

Reason: Permission Denied.

Can anyone help? If you need to know in more detail, feel free to let me know.

Comment: anyone might be able to help even just give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sdp` could be created by blueZ source code.

Therefore, you can create your own sdptool and then take advantage of this one to bind the socket. Surely, you have to `chmod` before you use it to gain ownership of that.

This approach works for me and hope this approach will be useful for you.